# In Vuetify, how can I put a sparkline component in a data table row?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create a [data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) that has a column that contains a [sparkline](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sparklines/) for each item in the data table.  Is that possible?

Here's a mock-up of what I'm aiming for:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to use the `item.name` slot. Create a separate column for chart, then use its slot to put the sparkline:

```
  headers: [
    {
      text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
      align: "start",
      sortable: false,
      value: "name",
    },
    { text: "Calories", value: "calories" },
    { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat" },
    { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs" },
    { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein" },
    { text: "Iron (%)", value: "iron" },
    { text: "Chart", value: "chart" },
  ],

  <template v-slot:item.chart={item}>
    <v-sparkline
      :value="value"
      :gradient="gradient"
      :smooth="radius || false"
      :padding="padding"
      :line-width="width"
      :stroke-linecap="lineCap"
      :gradient-direction="gradientDirection"
      :fill="fill"
      :type="type"
      :auto-line-width="autoLineWidth"
      auto-draw
    ></v-sparkline>
  </template>
```

Here is the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-hill-spwzs?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1174-1618