# In Vuetify, how can I use unique sparklines in a data table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create a Vuetify [data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) that has a column that contains a ***unique*** sparkline for each item in the data table. Is that possible?

There's this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054380/in-vuetify-how-can-i-put-a-sparkline-component-in-a-data-table-row) and [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-hill-spwzs?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1174-1618), but I'm struggling to modify it to have a unique sparkline per row. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

I have tried to add the sparkline 'value' array to the general data array in the linked example, like:

```
    {
      name: "Frozen Yogurt",
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
      iron: "1%",
      value: [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    },
```

But I don't know how to feed this value back into the sparkline  which only takes one array, and doesn't seem to accept a list of data arrays (one per row?)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add your code?

Comment: I have tried to integrate the 'value' array for the sparkline into the general data array: but I don't know how to feed this back into the sparkline data in the <template>

The sparkline only takes one array; I don't know how to iterate through unique arrays to display a unique sparkline per row.

Comment: Just added some code to the post - see the Sandbox example. My challenge is changing from the single 'value' array, to a unique 'value' array per row. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `<template v-slot:item.chart>` to `<template v-slot:item.chart="{ item }">`.
And change the sparkline `:value` to `:value="item.value"`.

Then in your desserts array add a value to each item like in your question.
Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-greider-148dim?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue).